# Как составить функции для работы кнопок?

Tags: python, tkinter

Выдали задание — создать приложение для работы с базой данных. Пока что с одной таблицей из базы. Изучали пока только Tkinter, поэтому и работаю в нём. Также для подключения к базе в PostgreSQL — Psycopg2.

Пока что создала только каркас для будущего приложения, красотой и функциональностью пока не занималась.

```
from tkinter import * 
import psycopg2 # импорт библиотек

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname = "bu_base", user = "postgres", password = "1", host = "localhost", port = '5432') #  подключение к базе данных в PostgreSQL

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT kontakti.id_klienta FROM bu_base.public.kontakti") # выбор всех строчек из поля "id_klienta"
id_klienta = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT kontakti.nazvanie FROM bu_base.public.kontakti")# выбор всех строчек из поля "nazvanie"
nazvanie = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT kontakti.kontaktnoe_litso FROM bu_base.public.kontakti")# выбор всех строчек из поля "kontaktnoe_litso"
kontaktnoe_litso = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT kontakti.telefon FROM bu_base.public.kontakti")# выбор всех строчек из поля "telefon"
telefon = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("SELECT kontakti.adres FROM bu_base.public.kontakti")# выбор всех строчек из поля "adres"
adres = cursor.fetchall()

root = Tk()


# Cоздание функции, которая будет рисовать внешний интерфейс для работы с конкретной таблицей.
def Formi():
    text_from_entry_0 = entry_0.get()
    number_of_string=int(text_from_entry_0) # Считывание информации из поля и преобразование в целочисленный тип.
    entry_1 = Entry(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white')
    label_1 = Label(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white', text = 'id_klienta', font = 'Candara 14', fg = 'black')
    entry_1.insert(END, id_klienta[number_of_string])

    entry_2 = Entry(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white')
    label_2 = Label(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white', text = 'Nazvanie', font = 'Candara 14', fg = 'black')
    entry_2.insert(END, nazvanie[number_of_string])

    entry_3 = Entry(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white')
    label_3 = Label(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white', text = 'Kontaktnoe_litso', font = 'Candara 14', fg = 'black')
    entry_3.insert(END, kontaktnoe_litso[number_of_string])

    entry_4 = Entry(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white')
    label_4 = Label(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white', text = 'Telefon', ont = 'Candara 14', fg = 'black')
    entry_4.insert(END, telefon[number_of_string])

    entry_5 = Entry(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white')
    label_5 = Label(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white', text = 'Adres', font = 'Candara 14', fg = 'black')
    entry_5.insert(END, adres[number_of_string])

    # ^ Создание текста и полей для ввода со внесёнными значениями из базы данных.

    but_1 = Button(frame_1, bg = 'white', fg = 'black')
    but_1["text"] = "Следующая запись"
    but_2 = Button(frame_1, bg = 'white', fg = 'black')
    but_2["text"] = "Отмена"
    but_3 = Button(frame_1, bg = 'white', fg = 'black')
    but_3["text"] = "Сохранить"

    # Кнопки "Следующая запись", "Отмена" и "Сохранить" соответственно.

    label_1.pack()
    entry_1.pack()
    label_2.pack()
    entry_2.pack()
    label_3.pack()
    entry_3.pack()
    label_4.pack()
    entry_4.pack()
    label_5.pack()
    entry_5.pack()

    # Упаковка всех виджетов, кроме кнопок.


     but_1.place(x = 50, y = 370)
     but_2.place(x = 200, y = 370)
     but_3.place(x = 280, y = 370)

    # Упаковка кнопок с выбранными координатами.

frame_1 = Frame(root, bg = 'white', bd = 150) # Создание фрейма.

entry_0 = Entry(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white')
label_0 = Label(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white', text = 'Введите номер записи: ', font = 'Candara 14', fg = 'black')

# Текст и поле для ввода номера записи.


but_0 = Button(frame_1, bg = 'white', fg = 'black')
but_0["text"] = "Продолжить" # Создание кнопки "Продолжить".
but_0.bind('<Button-1>', Formi) # Вызов функции "Formi".



frame_1.pack()
label_0.pack()
entry_0.pack()
but_0.pack()
# Упаковка всех виджетов.

root.mainloop()
```

Изображение работы ниже.

[image: То, как выглядит интерфейс при запуске.]

Дальше я хочу заставить работать кнопки. С этого начинаются мои проблемы. (Хотя мне кажется, что для многих это и не проблемы вовсе)

Начинаю с кнопки "Следующая запись". Для этих целей я хочу, чтобы бралась переменная number_of_string и к ней добавлялась единица, после чего бы записи заменялись на последующие.

Для этого я выносила начало функции Formi в отдельную функцию.

```
def Schitivanie():
    text_from_entry_0 = entry_0.get()
    number_of_string=int(text_from_entry_0)
    return number_of_string
```

Также добавила функцию "Next":

```
def Next():
    number_of_string += 1
    return number_of_string
```

После чего добавила события для кнопок "Продолжить" и "Следующая запись".

```
but_0.bind('<Button-1>', Schitivanie)
but_0.bind('<Button-1>', Formi)
but_1.bind('<Button-1>', Next)
bur_1.bind('<Button-1>', Formi)
```

Вылетала такая ошибка:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ritad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: Formi() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number_of_string'
```

Ну поняла, что это потому что функции я создала, но их результат никуда не записала.

В итоге текст приобретает такой вид:

```
from tkinter import *
import psycopg2


def Schitivanie(entry_0):
    text_from_entry_0 = entry_0.get()
    numb_of_string=int(text_from_entry_0)
    return numb_of_string

number_of_string = Schitivanie()

def Formi(number_of_string):

    entry_1 = Entry(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white')
    label_1 = Label(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white', text = 'id_klienta', font = 'Candara 14', fg = 'black', )
    entry_1.insert(END, id_klienta[number_of_string])

    entry_2 = Entry(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white')
    label_2 = Label(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white', text = 'Nazvanie', font = 'Candara 14', fg = 'black')
    entry_2.insert(END, nazvanie[number_of_string])

    entry_3 = Entry(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white')
    label_3 = Label(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white', text = 'Kontaktnoe_litso', font = 'Candara 14', fg = 'black')
    entry_3.insert(END, kontaktnoe_litso[number_of_string])

    entry_4 = Entry(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white')
    label_4 = Label(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white', text = 'Telefon', font = 'Candara 14', fg = 'black')
    entry_4.insert(END, telefon[number_of_string])

    entry_5 = Entry(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white')
    label_5 = Label(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white', text = 'Adres', font = 'Candara 14', fg = 'black')
    entry_5.insert(END, adres[number_of_string])


    but_1 = Button(frame_1, bg = 'white', fg = 'black')
    but_1["text"] = "Следующая запись"
    but_2 = Button(frame_1, bg = 'white', fg = 'black')
    but_2["text"] = "Отмена"
    but_3 = Button(frame_1, bg = 'white', fg = 'black')
    but_3["text"] = "Сохранить"


    label_1.pack()
    entry_1.pack()
    label_2.pack()
    entry_2.pack()
    label_3.pack()
    entry_3.pack()
    label_4.pack()
    entry_4.pack()
    label_5.pack()
    entry_5.pack()


    but_1.place(x = 50, y = 390)
    but_2.place(x = 200, y = 390)
    but_3.place(x = 280, y = 390)
    but_1.bind('<Button-1>', Next)
    but_1.bind('<Button-1>', Formi)
    but_2.bind('<Button-1>', Cancel)
    but_3.bind('<Button-1>', Save)



def Next(number_of_string):
    number_of_string += 1
    return number_of_string

number_of_string = Next()

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname = "bu_base", user = "postgres", password = "1", host = "localhost", port = '5432')
cursor = conn.cursor()


cursor.execute("SELECT kontakti.id_klienta FROM bu_base.public.kontakti")
id_klienta = cursor.fetchall()

cursor.execute("SELECT kontakti.nazvanie FROM bu_base.public.kontakti")
nazvanie = cursor.fetchall()

cursor.execute("SELECT kontakti.kontaktnoe_litso FROM bu_base.public.kontakti")
kontaktnoe_litso = cursor.fetchall()

cursor.execute("SELECT kontakti.telefon FROM bu_base.public.kontakti")
telefon = cursor.fetchall()

cursor.execute("SELECT kontakti.adres FROM bu_base.public.kontakti")
adres = cursor.fetchall()


root = Tk()


frame_1 = Frame(root, bg = 'white', bd = 150)

entry_0 = Entry(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white')
label_0 = Label(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white', text = 'Введите номер записи: ', font = 'Candara 14', fg = 'black', )



but_0 = Button(frame_1, bg = 'white', fg = 'black')
but_0["text"] = "Продолжить"
but_0.bind('<Button-1>', Schitivanie)
but_0.bind('<Button-1>', Formi)

frame_1.pack()
label_0.pack()
entry_0.pack()
but_0.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Вылетает это:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ritad\Downloads\Графический интерфейс к контактам(2).py", line 10, in <module>
number_of_string = Schitivanie()
TypeError: Schitivanie() missing 1 required positional argument: 'entry_0'
```

В общем, несколько дней я билась над этим. Понимаю, что чем дольше я не прошу помощи, тем больше сама себя путаю. Поэтому и пишу сюда. За помощь буду благодарна.

Comment: У вас функция `Schitivanie()` требует аргумента (`entry_0`), а вызываете вы ее без аргумента (`number_of_string = Schitivanie()`). Об этом в ошибке написано. Чтобы не вылетала ошибка, нужно функции дать аргумент)

Comment: @insolor Мне нужно просто написать entry_0 в аргументе? Вроде как она же выступает аргументом. Пишет, что '    number_of_string = Schitivanie(entry_0) / NameError: name 'entry_0' is not defined'. Так запуталась, что теперь не знаю, как распутаться.)

Comment: Маргарита, я сейчас постараюсь набросать ответ с рекомендациями по коду.

Comment: Ох, спасибо большое. Я вот думаю, что, может, где-то в другом месте ошибка. Или это как-то по-другому нужно делать.

Comment: "Kontaktnoe_litso" - prosto_vynos_mozga_iz_glaz.

Comment: @Other, лучше так, чем ContactFace, например)

Comment: @Other Нам сказали писать транслитом.)

Comment: @insolor Спасибо большое, что откликнулись. Я через некоторое время всё прочту.

Answer (score 2):

1. Текст программы обрабатывается интерпретатором сверху вниз, но функциям и классам только дается определение, и выполнение кода в них не происходит. Удобнее сначала дать определение всем функциям и классам, а потом использовать их.
2. Следует различать функции, которые вы вызываете вручную, и те функции, которые привязываете в качестве обработчиков событий Tkinter.

   Функции, которые вы вызываете самостоятельно, принимают аргументы и возвращают значения через `return`, и желательно чтобы они не использовали глобальных переменных.

   Функции-обработчики событий (для Tkinter) принимают один аргумент - `event` (описание события, по случаю которого была вызвана функция (например, клик кнопкой мыши)). Функции-обработчики событий всегда должны быть объявлены с этим аргументом, даже если они его никак не используют, т.к. Tkinter попытается его передавать, а передавать некуда (Ошибка `'TypeError: Schitivanie() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event' '` из комментария к другому ответу).

   Есть еще функции-обработчики, которые указываются через параметр `command`, например, у кнопок - они не имеют никаких аргументов вообще.

   Обработчики общаются с "внешним миром" через глобальные переменные или через поля класса, к которому они относятся (если функция является методом).

   В функции `Schitivanie` вы пытаетесь совместить обе роли, это получается не очень хорошо.
3. Имена аргументов, указанных при объявлении функций, никак не связаны с глобальными переменными, названными так же (например, `entry_0`, который является аргументом функции `Schitivanie`, никак не связан с глобальной переменной `entry_0`). Соответственно, глобальные переменные не подставляются автоматически при вызове функций с аргументами, названными так же. Если нужно обратиться к глобальной переменной из функции, просто обратитесь к ней, не добавляя ее имя в список аргументов функции (главное, чтобы переменная уже была доступна на момент вызова).

Исходя из этого:

```
# Сначала идут функции. Т.к. это функции-обработчики, то они должны принимать event
def Schitivanie(event):
    # глобальные переменные, которые функция меняет, должны быть объявлены как глобальные,
    # иначе функция просто создаст локальную переменную с тем же именем
    # и ее значение останется внутри функции
    global number_of_string
    text_from_entry_0 = entry_0.get()
    number_of_string = int(text_from_entry_0)


def Formi(event):
    # насколько я вижу, тут ничего не нужно объявлять, как глобальные переменные
    ...


def Next(event):
    global number_of_string
    number_of_string += 1
    # По идее эта функция также должна менять текст в поле entry_0, но могу ошибаться

# Дальше идет большой блок обращения к базе данных, вообще лучше его вынести в отдельную функцию
...

root = Tk()


frame_1 = Frame(root, bg = 'white', bd = 150)

number_of_string = 0  # Просто обнуляем значение (или присваиваем какое-то начальное значение)
# Изменение текста в entry делается через создание отдельной переменной Tkinter
entry_0_text = StringVar()
entry_0 = Entry(frame_1, width = 40, bd = 4, bg = 'white', textvariable=entry_0_text)
entry_0_text.set(str(number_of_string))

# Остальной код
...
```

Вообще, для Tkinter лучше использовать классы, это позволяет лучше структурировать программу, и избавиться от использования `global` (т.к. вместо глобальных переменных используются поля объекта). Я не сторонник объектно-ориентированного подхода, но программирование пользовательского интерфейса - это тот случай, когда ООП действительно полезен.

Я использую примерно такой вариант:

```
import tkinter as tk

# Тут идут функции и классы, не относящиеся к интерфейсу

# Главный класс приложения
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # Нужно запустить функцию инициализации родительского класса
        super().__init__()  

        # Тут идет создание и размещение всех элементов управления
        frame = tk.Frame(parent)
        frame.pack()
        
        self.entry_0 = tk.Entry(frame)
        self.entry_0.pack()
        self.number_of_string = 0
        
        bt1 = tk.Button(frame, text='Click me')
        bt1.pack()
        bt1.bind('<1>', self.bt1_click)
    
    def bt1_click(self, event):
        self.number_of_string = int(self.entry_0.get())

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Другие варианты можно посмотреть здесь: [SO: Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application%20Best%20wy%20to%20str)

Comment: +1 за поместить в класс и избегать global. Вот это в заблуждение может вводить: *"Поэтому лучше и удобнее сначала объявить все функции и классы, а потом вызывать их."* -- в Питоне нет объявлений функций, классов, есть только определения -- вы не можете вызвать функцию, не определив её (получите `NameError`, если имя не определено).

Comment: @jfs, с другой стороны, по-русски нельзя сказать "...сначала определить все функции и классы..." Как лучше написать тогда? Описать функции и классы? Дать определение функциям и классам?

Comment: я не понял вопроса. Что вы хотите сказать и как по вашему нельзя это выразить.

Comment: Может, я неправильно поняла Ваши слова "Тут идёт создание и размещение всех элементов управления". Хотела добавить Label и Listbox. `list_of_tables = ["kontakti", "zakazi", "tovari", "rabotniki", "shtat", "rabotaet", "ispolzuetsya", "oplata"] \
        label_0 = tk.Label(frame, text = "Выберите таблицу:")\
        listbox_0 = tk.Listbox(frame, selectmode = SINGLE)\
        i = 0\
        for i in list_of_tables:\
            listbox_0.insert(END, i)\
        label_0.pack()\
        listbox_0.pack()`
Выдаёт такую ошибку: `NameError: name 'SINGLE' is not defined`.

Comment: А это вроде как опция списков.

Comment: @МаргаритаДоронина, ошибка из-за того что tkinter импортирован не как `from tkinter import *`, а как `import tkinter as tk`, поэтому нужно указывать явно, например, что `SINGLE` взято из этого модуля: `tk.SINGLE`.

Comment: @insolor Постоянно случается, что не учитываешь какие-то мелочи, и вот ошибка. Спасибо ещё раз.

Comment: @МаргаритаДоронина, тут проблема в том, что в статьях по tkinter обычно модуль целиком импортируется в общее пространство имен, независимо от того, что понадобится, а что нет. Но хорошей практикой в Python является либо явно импортировать только то, что вам действительно нужно - или как `from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label` (и т.д.), или как `import tkinter as tk`, а потом использовать `tk.Tk`, `tk.Frame` и т.д.

Comment: @insolor Да-с, и учат нас тоже импортировать модуль целиком. А в чём различие?

Comment: @МаргаритаДоронина, отличие в том, что при импортировании как `from module import *` просто все высыпается в кучу, и вы не знаете что там есть. Если так импортируется несколько модулей, то может оказаться, что в них разные вещи (функции, классы) называются одинаково. А когда вы захотите использовать функцию, которая была в первом модуле, но была перезаписана функцией из второго модуля, которая делает что-то другое, то может быть довольно проблематично разобраться, почему программа не работает как надо.

Comment: @insolor Аа, ну тогда это не есть хорошо. Буду впредь знать.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в этой функции передать в качестве параметра "event"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 'TypeError: Schitivanie() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'
' — как это поправить?